# Variadic template function: specialize head/tail and empty base case

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I'd like to have a variadic template function inside a class. The variadic template arguments are chars which should be processed in a loop-like manner. So I thought of writing it like in haskell with head/tail splitting the list until a base case (empty list) is reached.

As an example, let's just count the number of arguments given (only a minimal example).

I came up with the following code:

```
struct MyClass {
    template<char ...X>
    static int count();
};


template<>
int MyClass::count<>() {
    return 0;
}
template<char Head, char ...Tail>
int MyClass::count<Head, Tail...>() {
    return 1 + count<Tail...>();
}
```

However, this [doesn't seem to work](http://ideone.com/ybuhxZ):

```
prog.cpp:12:35: error: function template partial specialization ‘count<Head, Tail ...>’ is not allowed
prog.cpp:12:5: error: prototype for ‘int MyClass::count()’ does not match any in class ‘MyClass’
prog.cpp:3:16: error: candidate is: template<char ...X> static int MyClass::count()
```

How can I achieve this? I know that partial specialization isn't supported for functions. But I thought that specializing a variadic template into head/tail and empty base case version isn't a *partial* specialization but a *full* specialization, but maybe I'm wrong? Do I need to write this as a class instead of a function?

I found examples (printf) which implement a base case without using the template syntax at all. But I guess that my case is different, since the call for printf doesn't use template syntax but *type deduction*, so `printf(tail...)` calls `printf()` if `tail` is empty. On the other side, in my case, when calling the base case, `count<>()` isn't the same as `count()`.

Comment: For the mentioned case, you could just create a tuple from the var arg, and the use tuplesize. Maybe tuples are easier to work with, with whatever else you have in mind?

Comment: @Skeen This was just a very minimalistic example at which the basic problem can be easily be discussed. Of course, I need something more complex. AFAIK, tuple only works with types, not with values.

Comment: Tuples can store data as well and they seem a lot easier to work with if you ask me.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I would say it is normally a better idea to overload function templates rather than specializing them:

```
struct MyClass {
    template<typename... Tail>
    static int count() {
        return 0;
    }

    template<char Head, char... Tail>
    static int count() {
        return 1 + count<Tail...>();
    }
};

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << MyClass::count<'f','o','o'>();
}
```

And here is a [live example](http://ideone.com/7SgiTL). I would also mention that the built-in operator `sizeof...` could be used for this purpose:

```
struct MyClass {
    template<char... Chars>
    static int count() {
        return sizeof...(Chars);
    //         ^^^^^^^^^
    }
};
```

Comment: Oh my gosh, totally forgot about overloading. Thanks! (off topic: LWS > ideone?)

Comment: Of course there is sizeof, the `count` was just the simplest example I could come up with, which still demonstrates the basic problem.

Comment: @leemes: Yes, I realized that, I only mentioned `sizeof...` for the sake of completeness, but I understand your intent

Comment: Okay. By the way: I just found out that `template<typename...>` can be anonymous, but `template<char...>` can't. If I understand it correctly: the base case needs to be a template. If I want it to be empty, I still have to say `template<SOMETHING>`, but SOMETHING can't be empty. A variadic template with `typename` will accept types, but there are never types (at least when not mis-using it). I first wrote `char...` as the base case, but this was ambiguous, of course. So this `typename...` is a hack for this "problem"?

Comment: @leemes: A parameter pack can be anonymous, and `SOMETHING` can be empty for function templates: see [here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/N6QE5$48). The `typename...` is a trick to make the call non-ambiguous